# Rules passed to lexer is order-sensitive

Tags: regex, parsing, compiler-construction, lexer

Say I am writing a lexer for scanning robots.txt.

Say I want to start with the old RFC (http://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt) and only want to do the most basic syntax:

```
# COMMENT
User-agent: Google
Disallow: /admin
Disallow: /foo.html
Allow: /bar/bar.html
```

The very basic rules would be like this in Python

```
_RULES = [
    (WHITESPACE, r"\s+"),
    (COLON, r":"),
    (COMMENT, r"#.+"),
    (UA_ID, r"user-agent"),
    (ALLOW_ID, r"allow"),
    (DISALLOW_ID, r"disallow"),
    (RPATH, r"(\/[a-zA-Z0-9|\:|\@|\&|\=\.]*)+"),
    (UA_VALUE, r".+"),
]
```

Note if we put `UA_VALUE` before `RPATH`, the greediness will match `/admin` to be `UA_VALUE`, which is not what we really want later in the parser process.

Now supposed I want my lexer to take in a set of "extension rules" (many robots.txt now have "custom" directives, which was foreseen in the old RFC as "extension").

An extension might be to support full URL instead of path fragement like `RPATH`. Or if we support `Craw-delay` which takes in numbers or fractions. Now the user has to insert the new extension rules into the `_RULES` in the right order to avoid matching to the wrong rule, producing the wrong kind of token.

I can see the problem with using regex incompetently, but I believe this order-sensitive issue can also exist in the hand-written, char-by-char, switch-statement based approach.

In general, can we avoid this ordering problem? Or do I attempt to "fix" the wrong token type later in the semantic analysis by "trying to fix" the kind of token by looking at its neighbors? It might work for trivial language like robots.txt. Do I need to break some of my rules further down to smaller unit? For example, instead of regex the entire `http/https://url...` I would do `http://` and `https://` as two separate token types.

Answer (score 1):

You could just include the <kbd>:</kbd> in the field-name tokens. Also, the "standard" insists that the declaration start in the first column, so you could also add an anchor operator (`^`). If that were not the case, you could dress the regex up a bit:

```
"^[[:blank:]]*Allow[[:blank:]]*:"
```

Beyond that, `robots.txt`, like many internet standards, does not yield very well to non-semantic lexical analysis. Individual directives have their own lexical rules. Unextended `robots.txt` is an easy case, since the only things that are allowed are (partial) URLs in the case of `Allow` and `Disallow` and arbitrary strings not containing a # in the case of `User-Agent`. But extensions might have their own formats.

My usual approach to parsing `field: value` protocols is to extract the field (using a simple regex like the one above), and then look the syntax up in a table which maps field-names to value-parsers. There are a variety of variants on this theme, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed one of my earliest approaches was to extract field and value in Python directly using named regex. Is it a good approach to unify UA_VALUE and RPATH as a single token type and process the semantic later in the parser?

Comment: @CppLearner: This problem might yield to the classic ARGC/ARGV technique where the rest of the line is tokenized into whitespace-separated "words", with trailing comments removed. It's then up to each individual command to deal with validating the syntax of its arguments; it just receives a list of words.